# Php Include - Subfolders

Tags: php, html, css, include

I'm using php include. Now the files are in the sub-folder.

The error goes exactly like this:

> Warning: include(/headertop.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\ROLDANKING\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\print_design.php on line 11

The HTML/PHP file is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PRINT DESIGN</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/art_favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/body.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

</head>

<?php include ("headertop.php"); ?>

<?php include ("header.php"); ?>

<?php include ("nav.php"); ?>

<body>


<div id="contents">

</div>

</body>


<?php include ("footer.php"); ?>

</html>
```

Comment: I am going to assume according to your question those files "headertop.php", "header.php", etc are somewhere else?

Where or what is the full path to those files in junction with "D:\ROLDANKING\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\print_design.php"

Comment: The warning shows a leading slash in the file name, so how come your posted code doesn't show it?

Comment: Hello Jack, I've used like (".../name/header.php") or ("/name/header.php) and a lot more...but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the paths correct and files in place you can try this...

```
<?php 
 include ("sub-folder/headertop.php");
 include ("sub-folder/header.php");
 include ("sub-folder/nav.php"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want to avoid is having to change the path to an include on each page. You can do that with something like this:

```
<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/header.php"; ?>
```

That will work nicely online, but to work in XAMPP, you need to set up a vitrual host so that the link points to the same thing: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

Comment: Why rely on *DOCUMENT_ROOT* at all? You're just introducing an external dependency. Simply use a path relative to the current script, ie `__DIR__ . '/includes/header.php'`

Comment: I don't know how to use `__dir__`, but from the mess I've read online, it looks like a fair bit of work. Would it allow the same link on all pages? If not, I prefer one thing that I can paste everywhere.

Comment: See [PHP: Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php). Using them makes your app portable and removes external dependencies. They are **not** hard to use

Comment: Thanks Phil. I did read that page beforehand, but sadly, it's just full of developer jiberish to me (that is, it only makes sense when you already know what it means—a common problem that developer docs don't appreciate.) A simple example, with a comparison to DOCMUMENT_ROOT usage, would be worth a thousand words.

Comment: *DOCUMENT_ROOT* has no place in the PHP manual. It is a web server concept. I'm not sure what's so hard to understand about *"`__DIR__` - The directory of the file"*

Answer (score 0):

Warning: include(/headertop.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\ROLDANKING\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\print_design.php on line 11

says there is NO headertop.php file in your directory
check if the file exists: `D:\ROLDANKING\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\headertop.php`

also you can just use:

```
<?php 
 include ("headertop.php");
 include ("header.php");
 include ("nav.php"); 
?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php include ("headertop.php"); ?>

<?php include ("header.php"); ?>

<?php include ("nav.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Hello Mike M. Thanks for the hand, I can't place the headertop.php on the "pages" folder because it's a constant. It is placed at the main folder called "mysite" together with the index.php, footer.php, header.php and so on.

Comment: so `D:\ROLDANKING\xampp\htdocs\mysite\headertop.php` is the page you want to include and `D:\ROLDANKING\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\print_design.php` so the headertop.php should be located in \pages\ if you want the main directory just use ../headertop.php this will be the ROOT directory

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include ("SUB_FOLDER/headertop.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
include '../headertop.php';
```

or

```
include '/headertop.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

I have come across dozens of webpages over the last 3 days and I think I have collectively tested exactly what most people coming here are looking for.

ABSOLUTE PATHS. They must be manually established on your local host, and then again on your Live website, but this is nothing shy of declaring a variable set to a particular pre-built function.

Stay with me..
Every time I reference a link in a php (includes and echos), or in html and css, I reference a variable set to the root directory + that original link.

e.g.

```
background-image: url(<?php echo $root; ?>images/bg-0.jpg);
```

The only downside to this is the visibility of extra code and tediousness of adding a $variable to each and every link in a css or php document. And lord forbid javascript, because I havent even touched the root of that. Heh. Puns.

Anyways, to make this work..
In my Styles.css Doc, I simply convert it to Styles.php, encase the CSS code in

```
<style type="text/css"> *CSS* </style>
```

tags, which enable the echo of a PHP variable but as a string, or in our case an absolute path precursor.
In my header file, I now include my CSS as a PHP include with a new Root Variable.

```
include $php_root.'includes/css/styles.php';
```

Notice how this $variable is different than the echo's? The way I declared the variables plays a huge role in how CSS/HTML perceives a root destination, and how PHP sees it.

So these were my set variables.

```
// WAMP Localhost
$root = "http://localhost/PZD/";
$php_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "PZD/";

// Live Server
$root = "http://prozechdesigns.com/";
$php_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

These may be set in your main header.php include itself.

Or if you're like me with database files to connect to and communicate with, you might pair it with a database connect.php file. I did; that way, when I call upon my init.php file or need to edit the init.php, I do not need to worry about which $root variables are being used after overwrite between localhost and live website.

You may not be using WAMP as you're reading this, and at your time and date or configuration, your PHP Root location may not be set like mine is. But if you are using WAMP and perhaps wish to find out where your root is set or change it, look for the httpd.conf file located by default in `"wamp/bin/apache/apache#/conf"`.